# State Transition Matrix for Extended Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter, transition-matrix

Sorry for what might be a long post, I want to give background.

Initially I had regular Kalman filter, and the state model was defined by Newtonian kinematics, with initial position 0 and speed of 2. I was tracking position (x) and velocity (v), i.e. my state vector is $\begin{bmatrix}
    x & \dot x \\
    \end{bmatrix}^T$:

$$x = x_0 + v_0t$$
$$v = v_0$$

This resulted in a State Transition Matrix:
$$    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \Delta t\\
    0 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Now I am trying to implement Extended Kalman Filter. I have given system Acceleration of 2, so that equations go like this together with plugging in initial speed and acceleration:

$$x = x_0 + v_0t  + \frac12at^2 \rightarrow x = 2t + t^2$$

$$v = v_0 + at \rightarrow v = 2 + 2t$$

Now I need to find Jacobian Matrix with respect to my state vector and I understand what it is, however, I do not understand, how do I find my State Transition Matrix, if equations that I have are expressed in terms of time and not in terms of the state variables. I assume that first line in State Transition Matrix remains the same, since position changes in same way, i.e:
$$position = previous\,position + \Delta time * speed\, over\, that \, time\, period$$
It is the speed that is changing. But I don't know how to define it in my State Transition Matrix. From what I understand, my STM will be different every epoch, am I right? As I said, I know that I need to find Jacobian and know what it is, but I don't know how to find it in this particular case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading a few tutorials on Kalman filter or "Optimal State Estimation" by Dan Simon. I think you are misunderstanding the Kalman filter, and your formulation doesn't make much sense. However, I will try to clarify some of the misunderstandings.

In a standard Kalman filter, the process model and observation models are linear i.e.,
$$ \mathbf{x}_k = \mathbf{A}_k \mathbf{x}_{k-1} + \mathbf{B}_k \mathbf{u}_k$$
$$ \mathbf{y}_k = \mathbf{C}_k \mathbf{x}_k$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the process model (or state transition matrix), $\mathbf{B}$ is the control input model, and $\mathbf{C}_k$ is the observation model (noting that I did not include the noise terms). The state and output are $\mathbf{x}_k$ and $\mathbf{y}_k$, respectively.
I suggest trying to write the matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ for your system.

For an extended Kalman filter, the process and observation models are nonlinear i.e.,

$$ \mathbf{x}_k = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_{k-1},\mathbf{u}_{k-1}) $$
$$ \mathbf{y}_k = \mathbf{h} (\mathbf{x}_k)$$

where $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ are vector valued functions (noting I did not include the noise terms here either). Now, in the nonlinear case, you do not have a state transition matrix because the system is nonlinear. If you do not understand why this is the case, you should start here, then as I said, look up some tutorials or the Dan Simon book. I hope this is helpful to you, but I prefer not to write entire KF tutorial here.

Now, to answer your question... the Jacobian $\mathbf{F}$ in general is given by 
$$ \mathbf{F}_k = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \Biggr|_{\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}} $$

where $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_{k-1|k-1}$ is your previous estimate of your state and $f$ is the process model. You provided the process model, so you can simply compute the Jacobian from this formula. If you need help with this, I suggest looking up how to compute partial derivatives. Then, after you are good on that part, try to apply this formula. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is sort of what I mean, but my problem isn't that really. I know that I am supposed to find Jacobian Matrix of f with respect to x, My equation of position is x = x_0 + v_0 * dt + 0.5 * a * dt^2, as you can see it is expressed in terms of time (t), but I need to find partial derivatives with respect to my state variables x and v. If I took derivative partial derivatives of t^2+2t with respect to x and then v, I would get all zeros....

Comment: You shouldn’t plug in acceleration. You need to try to write matrixes A, B, etc... Then, I think you will understood the issue.

Comment: I know what my matrices A and B are as I already have implemented Kalman filter beforehand. My question is how do i find lowercase f from the system model that I have

Comment: The function f is your model, so A and B make your f. For linear system, f(x,u) = Ax + Bu. You write your f in your question. Just don’t plug in acceleration, I assume that is your control input.